# Is it better for SEO to have multiple sub pages or all pages sumed up?

Tags: seo, redirects

I am doing a relauch of my site. `example.de/service` has 5 subpages. In my new layout I would love to put all subpages in the parent page (`/service`) together. But Google already indexed all subpages.

What should I do to not loose this Google "power"?

Should I leave it as it is and live with the subpages, or can I do redirects from the subpages to the `/service` page without loosing with Google? And if I am "losing", how bad is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: With a proper HTTP response status code 301 ([Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)) from the old subpages to the new `/service` one you'll be good.

Long version: It's complicated. The key for this given problem is that you are looking at a low traffic regional page with local customers only. There are not many companies in that region offering these services (is there any competition at all?). It would be a different story otherwise. For a non-regional webpage it would probably be better to keep the current structure because each subpage is more specialized for the given key words.

What you want to add is https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business because that will give Google the needed information to make local search more powerful.

And give Google some 4-8 weeks time for some soul searching.

Comment: Ok thank you! There is a little bit of competition from the thilemann store in Koblenz (not the same owner). 

But I think i`ll try the 301 method.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach depends on the content.

If each separate page (or sub page) contains enough paragraphs on a topic (almost like a storybook), then leave your setup as-is.

If however each page has very little content or even just maybe a few images by itself, then you're better off merging the pages together to form a story line so that more search engines can index your content.

The last thing you want guests to do is click the "next" button (or buttons similar to it) more often than viewing content. I bet that operation will strain some people's fingers over time. The point is, people want to see content they are looking for without making so many clicks.

And yes, if you decide to update the URLs, implement 301 redirects from the old URLs to the new URLs.